# Limits of app access tokens

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, publishing

Like many other people on the web I was worrying about the expiration of the 60-day access tokens because my app will do some async publishing and I cannot initiate re-athorization because those jobs run on the backend without any user-involvement. Then I disovered that there are "App access Tokens" (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/). And they can be used to publish 'on behalf of the user' without expiring. My question is: What are the limits of these app-tokens when publishing? Is there anything I can't publish with them?

Comment: The limitations of access tokens vary widely between issuers. Have you checked out the public Facebook API for this? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/ is where I'd start.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! Yeah, I did. I even tested it successfully and could publish the same message with a user- or app-token. Of course the user had to grant 'publish_actions' to my app. But I think he has to do that anyway, even if I use the user-token. (?)
That's when I started wondering 'Why are there so many discussions about 60-day-tokens & backend-publishing? I must have gotten something wrong about app tokens...'

Comment: Just read the docs once more and I can only see that on app-access-tokens there is a limit on the retrieval of information (which I fortunately do not need in my app). No limit on publishing mentioned. So I think I will go for the app-access-token...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Facebook support issue.