# Publishing message on fb/twitter simultaneously in offline mode

Tags: java, angularjs, facebook-graph-api, access-token

Imagine you've to implement following user story:
"User should be able to publish message on social media(facebook/twitter/etc) using simple web form and one-click button[without need to login in fb/twitter/etc]."

In general, authentication in social networks is based on OAuth 2.0. Facebook distinguish three types of access tokens:

1. User access token
2. App access token
3. Page access token

I've tried first option with facebook4j, and it's working - however, we are supposed to supply token each time, we want to use it. I've found long-lived tokens, but their validity is also limited - 60 days.
Generating app access tokens is very simple, but I haven't succeed in publishing any post. From facebook docs:

> App access tokens can also be used to publish content to Facebook on
>   behalf of a person who has granted an open graph publishing permission
>   to your application.

Page access tokens - I haven't tried. Is it possible to publish message on fb/twitter simultaneously, without login, of course, to predefined destination(fb wall)? If so, please provide me with any working example :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: autoposting on facebook is not allwed. every single entry on the user wall must be approved by the user, so you can just use a user token and refresh it whenever the user wants to post.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that I cannot post anything with app-access-token? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359646/limits-of-app-access-tokens

Comment: that´s not at all what i posted...but i am pretty sure you do need a user token with publish_actions.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#publish

Comment: "A user access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new posts."

Comment: @up Thanks for refs :) I've tried to grant public_actions to my app on https://developers.facebook.com/, but fb requires link, screenshots, descriptions and few other things. App is being developed, so I cannot provide such informations. Is there any other way to grant public_actions(development mode)?

Comment: fb does not require anything for development, why wouls you send it in for review if it´s not finished? publish_actions will work for everyone with a role in the app without review.